# Auto click enter in sign in pop up after run powershell script

Tags: powershell, powerbi, scheduled-tasks

I've powershell file (backup_dataflow.ps1) that download file from power bi service into local directory
But the problem is, I've to click an account of power bi pop-up (sign-in) for the first step to make the script run as picture below :

[image]

After I clicked on it, the script could be run :

[image]

I want to scheduled it using windows task scheduler but how to acomplish this power bi sign-in so it would be auto click enter in this window after the pop-up appeared?

Here's the powershell file :

```
# #Log in to Power BI Service
Login-PowerBI  -Environment Public  

#First, Collect all (or one) of the workspaces in a parameter called PBIWorkspace
# $PBIWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace              # Collect all workspaces you have access to
$PBIWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name "Ovie"   # Use the -Name parameter to limit to one workspace

#Now collect todays date
$TodaysDate = Get-Date -Format "yyMMdd_hhmmss" 

#Almost finished: Build the outputpath. This Outputpath creates a news map, based on todays date
$OutPutPath = "D:\Ovie\Powershell\pbi\" + $TodaysDate 

#Now loop through the workspaces, hence the ForEach
ForEach($Workspace in $PBIWorkspace)
{
  #For all workspaces there is a new Folder destination: Outputpath + Workspacename
  $Folder = $OutPutPath + "\" + $Workspace.name 
  #If the folder doens't exists, it will be created.
  If(!(Test-Path $Folder))
  {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Folder
  }
  #At this point, there is a folder structure with a folder for all your workspaces 
  
  #Collect all (or one) of the reports from one or all workspaces 
  $PBIReports = Get-PowerBIDataflow -WorkspaceId $Workspace.Id             # Collect all reports from the workspace we selected.
  #$PBIReports = Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $Workspace.Id -Name "My Report Name" # Use the -Name parameter to limit to one report
    
    #Now loop through these reports: 
    ForEach($Report in $PBIReports)
    {
      #Your PowerShell comandline will say Downloading Workspacename Reportname
      Write-Host "Downloading "$Workspace.name":" $Report.name 
      
      #The final collection including folder structure + file name is created.
      $OutputFile = $OutPutPath + "\" + $Workspace.name + "\" + $Report.name + ".json"
      
      # If the file exists, delete it first; otherwise, the Export-PowerBIReport will fail.
       if (Test-Path $OutputFile)
        {
          Remove-Item $OutputFile
        }
      
      #The pbix is now really getting downloaded
      Export-PowerBIDataflow -WorkspaceId $Workspace.ID -Id $Report.ID -OutFile $OutputFile
      # Export-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $Workspace.ID -Id $Report.ID -OutFile $OutputFile
    }
}
```

Sincerely,
Oviedityanto

Comment: this is clearly not the right approach. you need to use a service principal with delegated permissions.